# How to set selecteddate in material-calendarview

Tags: android

I want to add selected date from data that i get from table. here is my array example

```
{"data":[{"Tanggal":"2019-07-02","Flag":1},{"Tanggal":"2019-07-03","Flag":0}]}
```

for real i don't know how to do it, my teacher is google, but i think i miss something. so i'm trying to write it manual like this

```
String date = "2019-07-02";
        String parts[] = date.split("-");

        int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        widget.setDateSelected(calendar,true);
```

but i get an error

```
    widget.setDateSelected(calendar,true); // wrong 1st argument type
```

How can i achieve it , thanks in advance. 
Btw, i using this https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: might be the case of wrong import. That library has 2 methods with the name `setDateSelected()`. Cross check that

Comment: @MyNamels Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @NaitikSoni sorry for late reply, no i didn't

Comment: Ok...Which version of this library you are using??

Comment: @NaitikSoni i'm using     implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1'

Comment: @MyNameIs Check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another method `setSelectedDate(LocalDate date)` from this library to set the date.
Here is the code...

```
try{
    //Option 1
    String myDate = "2019-07-02";

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(myDate);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    //Option 2
    LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.of(2019,07,02);

    //and finally pass it in parameter
    widget.setSelectedDate(ld);//you can also pass ld1

}catch (ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And use below import for LocalDate

`import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;`